# What are all the functions that can be done using node js?

Tags: node.js

I am a node js beginner.. I have done several services in node js like insert/update/delete/e-mail using SMTP/chat using socket.. i would like to know about what else can be done using node js.

Comment: It's a programming language with thousands of libraries.  You do pretty much anything with it.  This question is far too broad for here.  An entire book could be written to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's documentation for all the stuff node comes with:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/
https://nodejs.org/api/

But that's barely it. Node's used widely due to the variety of packages written for it. Check out Node Package Manager (npm): https://www.npmjs.com/

As you can see, there are ~400,000 packages. Of course, the ones you're gonna be using depend on your requirement.

Some starting packages you should look at:

- Express—Web framework.
- Mongoose—Database interface